# Tor Browser Bundle will not open

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

In Windows 8.1 when I open "Start Tor Browser.exe" in  Windows Explorer nothing happens. Firewall and Antivirus are disabled

Comment: Have you tried redownloading the current release again in case th eine you have got corrupted somehow?

Comment: I have the same problem. When I click to open Tor nothing happens. When I press "Alt, Ctrl, Delete" and open task manager Tor is not even running in the process page.

Comment: Could you explain step by step what you are doing? Screenshots might help.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue... deleted and downloaded twice before I discovered the problem.

1. download the tor bundle
2. right-click the application file
3. At the bottom, click "Properties"
4. You will see a notice that says "This program seems to have come from another computer.." click the box to enable.
5. Now, double click the file, Tor install modal opens on screen.

cheers

Comment: Did this. could not find This program......etc
still does not work

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13446)