# Tor browser 4.0 doesn't start but process is running (win7)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, startup

I'm using Tor Browser 4.0 in Windows 7 32bit. When I start firefox.exe (or click the Start Tor Browser link, which is the same) a firefox.exe process starts, but no window shows up and after some time the process has a constant CPU use of 0%. Any thoughts on how to fix this? (btw, I usually have the firefox web browser open.)

Comment: Are you by chance running Trusteer Rapport? It seems to interfere with Tor Browser 4.0. See: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4411

Comment: nope. I've never heard of that piece of Software.

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems the issues lies in antivirus program. I am using webroot, i turned it off and works perfectly.

Comment: I don't get "this seems to come from another computer.." in my properties and TOR still wont open Please help

Comment: had exactly same problem with opening tor after updating it. wouldn't open. I have trusteer rapport working on my computer which is banking protection software and after disabling trusteer tor works again perfectly so obviously some sort of program on your computer doesn't like tor. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I get that problem behavior only occasionally, at which time I kill the process with task manager and restart TBB. (I also have never heard of Trusteer Rapport -  unless that's the software that banks sometimes offer... and I nevertheless haven't installed it.)

Comment: I do that too, but i have to kill the process like, 4 times until it starts, and then it often tells me I should reset the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is very frustrating, I know. After two hours of deleting and downloading, here is the solution:

- right-click the .exe file
- Open "Properties"
- At the bottom, you will see a checkbox that says "this seems to come from another computer.." then check to allow the file to run.
- Tor starts.

cheers

Comment: Are you sure that's there on Windows 7? That sounds like Windows 8 (as in [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/3272/71)).